# How to modify slim v3 response body before and after route execution?

Tags: php, slim

I'm unable to get response body in slim v3 and its always blank. My code is:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use \Slim\App as Slim;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config['determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware'] = true;

$app = new Slim(['settings' => $config]);

$mw = (function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $response = $response->withStatus(200)->write(' before ');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $response = $response->withJson(array('data' => $body)); // output should be {"data":" Hello, User  seq1  seq2 "}
    return $response;
});

$mw1 = (function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response = $response->withStatus(200)->write(' seq1 ');
    return $response;
});

$mw2 = (function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response->withStatus(200)->write(' seq2 ');
    return $response;

});

$app->add($mw);

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write(" Hello, $name ");
    return $response;
})->add($mw1)->add($mw2);

$app->run();
```

What I want to do is the following:

- I don't want to add withJson() at the end of each route just to encode my json and output to client (browser). I want the middleware to handle this for me after (any) route execution ends.
- I want to get the final body and assign it to an array like $data['data'] = $body and than json encode it and return the modified response.

P.S. Slim v2 was much easier than Slim v3

Comment: $body = $response->getBody()->getContents(); ... you need to rewind the body before you get the contents.

Comment: This $body = $response->getBody()->getContents(); is giving empty string. Can you provide any example to use rewind? I tried rewind but still with no luck...

Comment: you need to $response->getBody()->rewind(); ... then get the contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change `getContents()` for `__toString()` at the middleware `mw`. Another change that should be done is on `mw2`: you have to return the new response created.

Look the complete code:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use \Slim\App as Slim;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config['determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware'] = true;

$app = new Slim(['settings' => $config]);

$mw = (function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next): Response {
    $response = $response->withStatus(200)->write(' before ');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $body = $response->getBody()->__toString();
    $response = $response->withJson(array('data' => $body)); // output should be {"data":" Hello, User  seq1  seq2 "}
    return $response;
});

$mw1 = (function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next): Response {
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response = $response->withStatus(200)->write(' seq1 ');
    return $response;
});

$mw2 = (function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next): Response {
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response = $response->withStatus(200)->write(' seq2 ');
    return $response;
});

$app->add($mw);

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response): Response {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write(" Hello, $name ");
    return $response;
})->add($mw1)->add($mw2);

$app->run();
```

I hope it can help you.

PS: I prefer Slim 3 :D

Comment: I tried the same __toString() but was not working. Your code worked and finally I achieved for what I was looking for. Thanks alot mate...

Answer (score 2):

You can also get content in this way

Method #1

```
$streamBody = $response->getBody();
$streamBody->rewind();
$content = $streamBody->getContents();
```

Method #2

```
$streamBody = $response->getBody();
$streamBody->rewind();
$content = $streamBody->read($streamBody->getSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unable to get response body in slim v3 and its always blank.

i had the same issue and couldn't just figure out why am getting *empty body response*,  so i ended up adding `json_encode($my_value)` to my return variable and that was the magic. Now i can proceed with buying a new dog and probably getting married. Hope this helps someone.

```
/**
 * method - GET
 */
$app->get('/posts[/]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    // fetching all
    $result = $db->getAllPosts();
    return json_encode($result);
});
```

And on the other side

```
/**
 * GetPosts
 */
public function getAllPosts() {
    // Instantiate DBH
    // make a connection to mysql here
    $db = new PDO_Wrapper();
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM all_posts WHERE post_status = :Publish AND post_type = :Post ORDER BY post_date DESC");
    $binding_array = array(":Publish" => "publish", ":Post" => "post");
    $db->bindArray($binding_array);
    $results = $db->resultset();
    return $results;
}
```